# Импорт переменных в js

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите. Есть файл `settings.js` в нем задаются значения цвета элемента.

```
var buttonColor = "Red";
export {buttonColor};
```

Есть файл `main.js` он подключается в `html`.  Через него я меняю цвет элемента, заданный в сеттинге.

```
import {buttonColor} from './settings.js';


var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');

function changeButtonColor(button) {
  button.style.backgroundColor = settings.buttonColor;
}

changeButtonColor(submitButton);
```

Но такой импорт не работает. Наверно, потому что он не видит файл `settings.js`, т.к. я его не подключаю в `html`. Как можно сделать, чтобы значения, задаваемые в настройках можно было использовать в файле `main.js`? Смысл в том, чтобы в настройках были только параметры, а сама реализация была в другом файле. Я новичок, поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что еще не все браузеры нативно поддерживают модули ( [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) )
Поэтому, для того, что бы ваши модули работали, вам необходимо использовать специальные инструменты, которые на этапе сборки возьмут на себя ответственность в импорте/экспорте ваших модулей.

Один из самых популярных это [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). С его помощью можно организовать модульную структуру. Более того, для вашей цели модули не нужны. Вы можете на этапе билда пробросить глобальную переменную ( которая будет видна внутри модулей ) и там хранить настройки. В зависимости от окружения и ситуаций этот конфиг можно будет менять

Comment: я Вас правильно понял, что сборщик мне нужен в любом случае?

Comment: @Neykoqt пока что да, когда будет полная поддержка браузерами, можно без него ( хотя сборщик и другие фишки даёт )